# javamail: how to have two set of (System.getProperties())

Tags: java, properties, jakarta-mail, imap

I am writing a Java app that do pull from SSL IMAP store and then push each MimeMessage in another IMAP store, not SSL.

Some mail.imap.* properties are conflicting each other. How can I have two set of properties to keep independent the two IMAP store settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass different `Properties` when creating a new JavaMail `Session` instance using [Session.getInstance(properties)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance(java.util.Properties)).

Comment: To be clear, this means you should use two Session objects, each with its own properties.

Answer (score 1):

System.getProperties() gets the process environment variables. They can only be one set. If you want to read properties from a file you should use properties.getProperties(filename)